# How change device name into a zpool?

Tags: zfs

I removed two disks from a freranas system. These two disks are formatted in ZFS. These two discs are configured in Mirror (RAID1). I have inserted these two disks on another system but I did not input the ZPOOL export command on the previous system.

By running the ZPool Import command on the new system seems to have been running because if you run the ZPool list command, the import zpool is shown.

My problem is now that the imported ZPool has the old names for the disks (SDA, SDB) while on the new system Discs are called SDB1 and SDC1

How can I correct the ZPool to use the new disk names?

Comment: I would export and import, however I think zfs know excat actual device name.

Comment: The sdb1 and sdc1 devices results unmounted on my system and appears at system as two fisical devices instead of one. I'll add some pictures to my question for a better description of my problem. Thanks

Comment: I realize this advice comes too late, but this is an excellent reason to create VDEVs using GPT labels rather than physical device names.  To address your question, someone may be more likely to help if you can edit your post to include the output of `zpool status`.

Comment: I resolevd. The import went well. Actually the zpool had been mounted on the root with name NAS. From the devices I see two disks but linux only sees one if I access the zpool (folder) created in root. So I asked myself a problem that really didn't work because I was looking at the wrong point. Thank you all for the help.